# efficient concatenation of lists in pandas series

Tags: python, list, pandas, concatenation

I have the following series:

```
s = pd.Series([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']])
>>> s
0    [a, b]
1    [c, d]
2    [f, g]
dtype: object
```

what is the easiest - preferably vectorized - way to concatenate all lists in the series, so that I get:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

Thanks!

Comment: `s.sum()` is the easiest vectorised way, but it's probably not very efficient...

Comment: awesome! good enough for me! thanx a lot

Comment: @ajcr should be an answer!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A nested list comprehension should be much faster.

```
>>> [element for list_ in s for element in list_]
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']

>>> %timeit -n 100000 [element for list_ in s for element in list_]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.2 µs per loop

>>> %timeit -n 100000 s.sum()
100000 loops, best of 3: 50.7 µs per loop
```

Directly accessing the values of the list is even faster.

```
>>> %timeit -n 100000 [element for list_ in s.values for element in list_]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.77 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not timing or testing these options, but there's the new pandas method [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas.Series.explode), and also `numpy.concatenate`.

Comment: Seems like `explode` takes much more time than other options:
```
%timeit -n 100000 [element for list_ in s for element in list_]
2.17 µs ± 97.6 ns per loop

%timeit -n 100000 [element for list_ in s.values for element in list_]
1.76 µs ± 209 ns per loop

%timeit -n 100000 [element for element in s.explode()]
77.4 µs ± 5.08 µs per loop

%timeit -n 100000 [element for element in s.explode().values]
76.4 µs ± 7.02 µs per loop
```