# How to get frequency of each element in column (having array of strings) of data frame with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a panda data frame in python as below:

```
df['column'] = [abc, mno]
               [mno, pqr]
               [abc, mno]
               [mno, pqr]
```

I want to get the count of each item below :

```
abc = 2, 
mno= 4 ,
pqr = 2
```

I can do iteration over the each row to count but this is not the kind of solution I m looking for. 
If there is any way where I can use iloc or anything related to that, please suggest to me.

I have looked at various solutions with a similar problem but none of them satisfied my scenario.

Comment: How about you use `.explode()` and `value_counts()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556050/efficient-concatenation-of-lists-in-pandas-series and value_counts

Comment: i understand comprehension will be faster than iteration yet.. i was expecting some easy solution using pandas api..

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I'd solve it using `.explode()` and `.value_counts()` you can furthermore assign it as a column or do as you please with the output:
In one line:

```
print(df.explode('column')['column'].value_counts())
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
data_1 = {'index':[0,1,2,3],'column':[['abc','mno'],['mno','pqr'],['abc','mno'],['mno','pqr']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df = df.set_index('index')
print(df)
           column
index            
0      [abc, mno]
1      [mno, pqr]
2      [abc, mno]
3      [mno, pqr]
```

Here we perform the `.explode()` to create individual values from the lists and value_counts() to count repetition of unique values:

```
df_new = df.explode('column')
print(df_new['column'].value_counts())
```

Output:

```
mno    4
abc    2
pqr    2
```

Comment: You can also explode a series directly, e.g. `df["column"].explode().value_counts()`.

Comment: Yes, I had the feeling OP was dealing with more columns (specially because of the ML tag)

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

Counter(chain.from_iterable(df.column))

Out[196]: Counter({'abc': 2, 'mno': 4, 'pqr': 2})
```

---

**%timeit**

```
df1 = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

In [227]: %timeit pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(df1.column)))
14.3 ms ± 279 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [228]: %timeit df1.column.explode().value_counts()
127 ms ± 3.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: @AlexHall: it is 8x faster than `explode` and `value_counts` when using `chain.from_iterable` to flatten on big dataframe

Comment: I take it back, the Counter API is implemented in Python but the actual counting is in C. My tests confirm that it is faster than value_counts, and `from_iterable` is faster than `explode` (maybe this warrants a pandas issue?)

Comment: @AlexHall: nothing serious. Cheers! it is well-known that `np.concatenate` is slower than `chain.from_iterable` in flattening lists. It's just a lazy part of me to use it instead of `from_iterable`. I switched to `from_iterable` just to show the true speed of `Counter` :)